# 'x64_mingw' is not a valid platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run **rails new** app command the process stops at bundle giving me the above error.
I have ruby 2.0.0p195, rails 4.2.0.beta4. I m trying to follow on Michael Hartl's tutorial. The command worked fine I think until I installed this version of rails... I tried to uninstall it but it looks like gem uninstall does not want to work. What should I do?

Comment: We need more context to help you. Your stack trace would be helpful in this situation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

check your gemfile you will see there like this 
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin] OR
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]

if you have gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]
then replace this with 
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]

and after that save file and fire bundle update command .

Comment: can you elaborate why this happens? I have no clue about Ruby/Gems

Comment: Care to explain more?

Comment: I have a development environment running under WIndows and a remote server running under Linux. If I remove `x64_mingw` it won't work under windows. If I keep it, I have this error only when trying to run `bundle exec rails c` from the capistrano `/current` deployment folder. The app itself with Phusion Passenger works well, but I cannot access the rails console via SSH.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are on Windows machine, right? I had the same problems, tried a lot of things only to be defeated by the same error that brought you here.

My fix:
1. Uninstall both Ruby and Rails and Rails Installer and anything related to RoR you have installed so far on your machine. Go to Control Panel to do so.
2. Visit http://railsftw.bryanbibat.net/ and download Ruby on Rails installer.
3. Use Ruby on Rails.