# Redmine requires bundler 1.5.0 or higher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, apache, bundler, redmine

I am trying to set up RedMine on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS machine and in the end of install have following error:

```
Redmine requires Bundler 1.5.0 or higher (you're using 1.3.5).
Please update with 'gem update bundler'. (SystemExit)
```

However, `gem update bundler`gives me following:

```
gem update bundler
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
```

Moreover:

```
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.15.3

$ gem list | grep bundler
bundler (1.15.3)
```

I am totally stuck.
Could anybody tell me how to fix it?
I've tried to remove Bundler version check in Gemfile. Then I have following error:

```
`x64_mingw` is not a valid platform. The available options are: [:ruby, :ruby_18, :ruby_19, :ruby_20, :mri, :mri_18, :mri_19, :mri_20, :rbx, :jruby, :mswin, :mingw, :mingw_18, :mingw_19, :mingw_20] (Bundler::GemfileError)
```

I've checked solutions here: http://www.redmine.org/issues/19409 and here http://www.redmine.org/issues/19469 - nothing helps...
After this steps: [Redmine installation : Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397506/redmine-installation-error)
I have `cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)` error. But bundler is installed and still have version 1.15.3 
Please help. I am totally disappointed with these errors.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: try "gem uninstall bundle" and "sudo gem uninstall bundle" then "gem install bundle" (with sudo if you have installed as such)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Tried. Now have `Could not find i18n-0.7.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)` error. However in `bundle list` output:
`* i18n (0.7.0)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
bundle clean
```

to remove all bundled gems

Then

```
bundle install
```

to install required gems

Edit:

After seeing your new error, look at this answer:

['x64_mingw' is not a valid platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096622/x64-mingw-is-not-a-valid-platform)

And this RedMine board post:

http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/45759

An updated bundler gem should be ok, but also check your `Gemfile` and remove any reference to `x64_mingw` before running `bundle install`

Comment: Thank you for answer! Tried. Didn't help as a pity... :(